# What does, "feed not found" mean?

Tags: flutter, dart

What does the following error mean?

> Uncaught (in promise) Error: Invalid argument(s): feed not found

Code:

```
var feed1 = await RssService().getFeed();
```

OR

```
final AtomFeed feed1 = await RssService().getFeed();
```

RssService:

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:webfeed/webfeed.dart';

class RssService {
  final _targetUrl = 'https://rss.app/feeds/_DawozSyanCYfGaQg.xmlRSS%20Feed';

  Future<AtomFeed> getFeed() =>
      http.read(_targetUrl).then((xmlString) => AtomFeed.parse(xmlString));
}
```

I renamed my variable feed to feed1 and the message did not change.  So this leads me to believe it is not referencing the variable, but some internal object.

Comment: Did you check the content of xmlString? Does it actually contain feed data?

Comment: just search `feed`  in VS code..then you will know which part you using it.

Comment: @nvoigt How do I check the xmlString?  I don't know how to separate the method and the lambda.

Comment: @John Joe, thats the problem, there is NO feed in my code

Comment: try flutter clean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method `AtomFeed.parse` will throw such an error, when the xml you gave it does not contain a node named "feed".

And the XML I get when I enter your URL in a browser does indeed not contain such a node.

Maybe you meant to use `RssFeed.parse` to get an RSS feed from that XML? Because that is what it looks like.